# system() Function on Mac didn't support multi-thread?

Tags: macos, darwin

I try to create some threads to ping different servers by `system()` function on Mac.  The code looks like this:

```
sprintf(str,"#!/bin/sh\n ping -c 3 -t 3 -o %d.%d.%d.%d \n",dataIP1[0],dataIP1[1],dataIP1[2],dataIP1[3]);
int ret =system(str);
```

But I found if there was a server unavailable, the last threads have to cost more than 3s to ping this servers and also even if this server is available. So I guess that the `system()` function does not support multi-thread. It looks like there is a locker inside itself, so it can only do the job one by one even you invoke it in different thread at the same time.

Is it correct?

Comment: system has never been "multithread". it simply fires up a shell and runs whatever command(s) you pass to it. If you want to run multiple pings in paralle, then do `ping ip1 & ; ping ip2 &; etc...` so that one single shell has each ping running in the background.

Comment: Since `system(3)` invokes `sh -c` directly, there is no need for the shbang line in a pretend-shell-script fashion here.